# using Python.h in c++ gives "no such file or directory" error

Tags: python, c++

I have been trying to include Python.h in c++ file.

```
#include "Python.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

This gives

```
fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

compilation terminated.

upon compilation.

I have correctly installed and added the directory to the PATH

```
echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/include:/usr/local/lib:/usr/include/python2.7
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Compilers don't use the PATH they use the INCLUDE PATH to find include files.   If you tell us what operating system and compiler you are using, we could tell you more.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and I got the compiler by sudo apt-get install g++

Comment: So i have bunch of files in Python2.7 folder should I move those .h files to the /usr/include directory?

Comment: I just solved the problem by putting all .h files to the /usr/include directoy and compile with the flag -lpython2.7. How can I make this question as solved?

Comment: Post the answer as an answer and accept it :)

Comment: As @GreenAsJade said, but note that there are waiting periods for answering you own question and marking it as accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer